# Amazon DynamoDB (NoSQL db) one-to-many relationship

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Since [Parse.com](http://parse.com) service announced about shutting down, I decided to rebuild my app using Amazon Web Services. As far as I understood Parse uses NoSQL (MongoDB) database and I was able to setup in Parse dashboard one-to-many relationship.

I successfully created a DynamoDB table `"Post"` with hash `"_id"`:

```
{
 "_id":"1"
}
```

and table `"Comment"` with hash `"_id"` and range `"post_id"`:

```
{
 "_id":"1",
 "post_id":"1",
 "text":"my comment"
}
```

Now, I want to fetch the post `_id = 1` with all comments related to this post. What are basic approaches to implement this? I think to define a Lambda function which will make two queries to DynamoDB:

1. Fetch Post
2. Fetch Comments with post_id
3. Construct Post with Comments Model and return it

Is it efficient way to design the one-to-many relationship?

Comment: What you've described is the correct way to do this using DynamoDB.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you, I will post then a Lambda function as an answer to help Parse community to adapt their databases to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I promised, posting my lambda function to fetch "relation" of your post. It instantiates a dynamodb instance and makes a query with parameters you provide. Long story short, you need to provide in ExpressionAttributeValues `post_id` of comments you are interested in.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();    
  var comment_params = {
      "TableName": "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
      "Select":"ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
      "IndexName": "YOUR_GLOBAL_INDEX",
      "Limit": 10,
      "ConsistentRead": false,
      "KeyConditionExpression": "#post_id = :v1",
      "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
          ":v1": {"S": "POST_ID"}
      },
      "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#post_id": "post_id"},
      "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL"
  }

  dynamodb.query(comment_params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
            return callback(err);
      } else {
          var comment_items = data.Items;
            return callback(null, comment_items);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your design, one issue you'll run into is the ability to query the Comments table by `post_id`. DynamoDB requires you to provide a hash key value when making queries, so things that are trivial in relational databases, such as joins, can actually become rather difficult with DynamoDB.

One way you might try to mitigate this is by creating a GSI (Global Secondary Index) on your Comments table, with a partition key on `post_id`.

The other option is to make the hash key in the Comments table the `post_id` and the range key the `comment_id` or a `timestamp`.

I hope this helps but if you still have questions I would encourage you to reach out to Amazon customer support via the [Forums.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131)